# The cheapest way to handle a string with C api of R?

Tags: string, r

I've asked previously a few question about R, thanks for the answers.

I've been more familiar with string(character) in R now, and knew that there are the differences between scalar character and vector.

But I still have a question about how to effectively handle string with C api of R? Here `"handle"` I mean to allocate memory for a string, and read or write data to it.

For example, the following is the code for processing(handling) a string:

```
SEXP processing(SEXP v)
{
    SEXP ans = R_NilValue;
    PROTECT(v = AS_CHARACTER(v));
    const char* src = CHAR(STRING_ELT(v, 0));
    size_t src_len = strlen(src);
    char *dst; 
    size_t dst_max_size;

    do_some_processing(src, src_len, dst, &dst_max_size);

    PROTECT(ans = NEW_CHARACTER(1));
    SET_STRING_ELT(ans, 0, mkCharLen(dst, dst_max_size));
    UNPROTECT(2);
    return ans;
}
```

I doubt if handling a string with a string vector is the most effective way to process a string.

So, is the above code the cheapest way to do the processing, with C API like `STRING_ELT`, `NEW_CHARACTER`, `SET_STRING_ELT`? Here `cheap` is in the perspective of `time and space overhead`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the manual "Writing R Extensions". There is no other documentation for the C API of R.

Comment: There are a few notes at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#modifying-strings. Also microbenchmark is your friend: brainstorm possible approaches and then benchmark.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for the link. I've never heard about microbenchmark, then I googled it and learned something.